# Where does video will be saved?

Tags: node.js, express, video, storage

I want to create a YouTube Clone site using NodeJS but before I start scratch it, I just wanna know where the video will be saved? Is it will saved in the tmp folder as we store pictures on this folder?

Comment: I have tried to save the pictures and as we know, it does save on the tmp folder. But for the uploading videos, I don't do anything yet and I bet it will also save on tmp. Well, that is what I've imagined right now.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to store videos on a cloud service like S3 and get them with their url's.